# WP8.1 Draw XAML Line On MapControl Between Two Points

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, maps

I am writing an application for Windows Phone 8.1, part of the app requires a line to be drawn between two locations on a map. I have the map set up and the code that calculates the two locations is in place and working.

I am looking for a very simple tutorial or guide for drawing a line between two Geopositions on a MapControl.

I understand how I would draw an ellipse about a specific point, however I couldn't find anything about drawing a straight line between two points.

During my research I did come across a library called WpWinNlMaps, however I couldn't find a way to implement this to achieve what I want.

Please let me know if any further information/context is required and any help is greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this problem for a while now.

Thanks,
      Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about Polylines, i tryed them once only on android, but they should work also in windows phone, here is the documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681899.aspx

hope they works for you!